# Can I have a GROUP BY as an expression? Without an alias

Tags: database

I want to be able to achieve the following query.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)*(60)) AS datetime,
ROUND(MAX(value), 2) AS value 
FROM  my_values v
WHERE (datetime > '2012-12-15 00:00:00') AND (datetime < '2013-01-01 00:00:00')  
GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)
ORDER BY datetime;
```

You'll notice that my groupby clause is dynamic, so far in Drupal I have:

```
$select = db_select('my_values', 'v')
  ->condition('datetime', '2012-12-15 00:00:00', '>')
  ->condition('datetime', '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '<')
  ->groupBy('gbdatetime')
  ->orderBy('datetime', 'DESC');
$select->addExpression('FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)*60)', 'datetime');
$select->addExpression('ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)', 'gbdatetime');
$select->addExpression('ROUND(MAX(value), 2)', 'value');
```

This achieves the desired results, however It'd be great if I could do a `GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)` without requiring the alias `gbdatetime`.

So, my question is can I have a `GROUP BY` as an expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use the following code.

```
$select = db_select('my_values', 'v')
  ->condition('datetime', '2012-12-15 00:00:00', '>')
  ->condition('datetime', '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '<')
  ->orderBy('datetime', 'DESC');
$select->addExpression('FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)*60)', 'datetime');
$select->addExpression('ROUND(MAX(value), 2)', 'value');
$select->groupBy('ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)');
```

Using `print (string) $select`, I get the following output.

```sql
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)*60) AS datetime, ROUND(MAX(value), 2) AS value
FROM 
{my_values} v
WHERE  (datetime > :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (datetime < :db_condition_placeholder_1) 
GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: For some reason when I tried this originally it failed. However It works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved like so:

```
$select = db_select('my_values', 'v')
  ->condition('datetime', '2012-12-15 00:00:00', '>')
  ->condition('datetime', '2013-01-01 00:00:00', '<')
  ->orderBy('datetime', 'DESC');
$select->addExpression('FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)*60)', 'datetime');
$select->addExpression('ROUND(MAX(value), 2)', 'value');

$groupBy = &$select->getGroupBy();
$groupBy['gb'] = 'ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)';

$result = $select->execute();
```

Which creates this query:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)*60) AS datetime,
ROUND(MAX(value), 2) AS value 
FROM my_values v 
WHERE (datetime > '2012-12-15 00:00:00') AND (datetime < '2013-01-01 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60) 
ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include any SQL expression with [addExpression](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3aaddExpression/7)

> An expression can be any arbitrary string that is valid SQL. That
>   includes various functions, which may in some cases be
>   database-dependent. This method makes no effort to correct for
>   database-specific functions.
>
> $alias: The alias for this expression. If not specified, one will be
>   generated automatically in the form "expression_#". The alias will be
>   checked for uniqueness, so the requested alias may not be the alias
>   that is assigned in all cases.
>
> Source: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7

Comment: Thanks David, the `addExpression` function states that it 'Adds an expression to the list of "fields" to be SELECTed.' I want to be able to do `$select->groupBy('ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)')` but group by only accepts aliases.

Comment: Why not just `$select->addExpression('ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)', 'gbdatetime')->groupBy('gbdatetime')` as per your example?

Comment: As stated in the question, that works fine. My question is how can I do it without having to select an additional alias field. In my example above I now have an extra `gbdatetime` field in my results. However in SQL I can `GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)/60)` without having to use an alias.

Comment: @thepearson What's actually worrying you about having an extra field selected in the query? The only thing I can think of is that it's a huge field that you don't want to return to the client app for performance reasons. If that's the case, however, you don't want to be aggregating that column anyway. Could you elaborate on the problem? A `SelectQuery` doesn't offer the functionality you're after because it would be considered non-standard. Many would argue you should _always_ select the grouped column anyway so it can be re-used sensibly in the remaining query

Comment: It doesn't worry me. I am not using it. It's redundant. I just want to know if I can do it without, since I can with MySQL directly.

Comment: @thepearson If you want to write arbitrary SQL, you can use db_query instead.

Comment: But for what reason do you want to do without? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I am aware of the many ways to achieve the results I need. That's not the issue. My question was simply if I can use a groupBy function with an expression as opposed to an alias. "No". is a perfectly acceptable answer, if someone knows that for sure.

Comment: @thepearson No. :)

Comment: @thepearson I still can't for the life of me work out why you need to know how to do that (unless its blind curiosity), as you say it's redundant. Nevertheless, nice inventive way to solve the problem +1 :)